# Perl script for creating a new job and configuring it in Jenkins

Tags: perl, jenkins

I need a Perl script through which I can create a new job and configure it by giving parameters in the script.
I have logged-in successfully in Jenkins through the script.
How do I consider the response from the login page and raise a new request to the server?

Because by using

```
$request->url("$jenkins_url"); # 1st time for login

$request->url("$jenkins_url/view/All/newJob/"); # 2nd time for new job
$response = $browser->request($request);
```

multiple times (once in login and the second time for creating a new job) it gives a 404 error for the second time.

Should I consider cookies? In such case, how should I?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you need to review the [CLI documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) for Jenkins.

The CLI comes as standard with Jenkins and is available at this URL:

```
<jenkins_url>/cli/
```

> You can access various features in Jenkins through a command-line
>   tool. See the wiki for more details of this feature. To get started, download jenkins-cli.jar, and run it as follows:
>
> ```
> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ help
> ```

Specifically you need to download the JAR file (from the link) and connect Perl to Jenkins using the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command:

```
 <jenkins_url>/cli/command/create-job
```

Which if you point a browser at it it will give you instructions.

> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ create-job NAME 
>   Creates a new job by reading stdin as a configuration XML file.
>
> ```
> NAME : Name of the job to create
> ```

Working example running a Groovy script

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $cmd = 'java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/jenkins groovy =';

my $groovy = "
['a','b','c'].each{
  println it
}
";

open F, " |  $cmd" || die "cannot open pipe: $!\n";

print F $groovy;
close F;
```

The '=' waits for Groovy to be sent on STDIN. Which is sent with print.

Closing the file (F) sends an EOF so the CLI will process the script.

My Jenkins server is on `localhost:8080/jenkins`.

Should you want more control, such as collecting the output, then you can use `|-` as described in [Bidirectional-Communication-with-Another-Process](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Bidirectional-Communication-with-Another-Process)

Comment: Thank you @KeepCalmAndCarryOn.
I tried this command ,
 my $cmd = 'java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ get-view simple';
  system($cmd);    this works for all except for creating and updating views or jobs..
How to give xml file as STDIN through this command?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Updated answer with an example to run a groovy command sent with SDTIN

Answer (score 0):

By using jenkins-CLI you can configure a new job. But for that you need to have an XML file. Without an XML file you cannot create a new job.

Perl code to create a new job in Jenkins:

`system('java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ create-job job_name  < "path to xml file"');`